# multiple matching between two data frames

Tags: r, matching

I have two data frames. One contains species occurrences in counties and the second has attributes for each county. Here is an example toy dataset.

```
species = c(rep("sp1",4),rep("sp2",3),rep("sp3",2)) ## species name
county = c("A","B","C","D","A","B","c","A","B") ## county occurrence
df=data.frame(species,county) 
County=data.frame(county=c("A","B","C","D"),attribute=c(1:4)) ## county data frame
```

I want to create a dataset that contains, for each row of df, the county level attributes associated with the species. This is easily enough done with match.

However, I want to find out, for each County, the species that are associated with that county from df. In this case match() only returns the first encounter. I want to return all of the matches. For example, for county A, there would be a row for sp1, sp2, and sp3.

I have a way of doing this with a loop that subsets for each individual species, but it is slow and I am wondering if there is a quicker way. Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the merge function should do what you need; you can think of it as the JOIN operation from SQL or other database query languages.

```
merge(df, County, by='county')
```

the by argument can accept multiple variables via the 'c' function, and if the column(s) to join on are different between data frames you can use by.x and by.y.

as an aside, the symbol 'df' is already used by a standard function (the density function for the F distribution), which is usually bad to overwrite.